# Best practices upgrading web app on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

Let’s say I've already deployed a web app on EC2, maybe thru FTP or Remote desktop. So from now on, what would be the best way to update to a new version of my web app?

My main concern would be when running several instances of that web app behind the load balancer: is there a way to update all instances at once so that there are never two instances running with different versions of the web app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Remove each instance from the load balancer (using the API or AWS management console) and update its software, until there is only one instance left. Upgrade that one without removing it, then re-add all the other instances.

There will be no time when the load balancer sends your traffic to two different versions of the software.

Comment: This is a valid answer, but unfortunately it does not scale. if you need several load-balanced instances to carry the load at all times, it will not work.